# Second SQL command in a transaction doesn't run

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to run 2 SQL commands (1 read, 1 delete) within 1 transaction in .NET.  Here's what I'm doing:

```vb
Using tran = objConn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)
    Using command As New SqlCommand("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE cost > 1", objConn)
        command.Transaction = tran
        Using dr As SqlDataReader = scOnDemand.ExecuteReader()
            While dr.Read
                some_list.Add(dr("foo"))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    Using command As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM bar WHERE cost > 1", objConn)
        command.Transaction = tran
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()                 //Doesn't do anything
    End Using
End Using
```

The idea is to keep the 2 queries atomic, but for some reason the DELETE isn't working.  The `SqlDataReader` reads just fine, and it does go into the second `using` statement but `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` doesn't seem to do anything.  Any reason why it's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions needs to end with a [Commit or Rollback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit?view=netframework-4.8). If you don't call `Commit` then at the end of the using block a Rollback is automatically called and, of course, the deletion is not executed.

```
Using command As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM bar WHERE cost > 1", objConn)
    command.Transaction = tran
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()                 
End Using
tran.Commit()
....
```